# Collapsable list of names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of names that I have to display in this table. I would like to only display
ONE name from this list and have that name clickable to show the rest from the list.

Maybe I am just over-complicating the problem.

Also I am trying to have the code not expand the table once clicked. And how could I align the names on the list in front of the `Names:`.

I wonder if anyone here would have a better way of accomplishing this or could point out where in this code it could be implemented.

I am trying using a less complicated code now, but cant align vertically the "" vertically next to the Names in the .

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head><title>Collapse List Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.min.js"></script>
<style>
 ul.list {padding-top:1px;list-style-type: none; padding-left: 3.0em;vertical-align: top;}
 ul li ul {
 display: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 padding:40; margin:20;
} 
</style>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.list > li a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
  });
 });
 </script>
   </head>
  <body>
  <br>

 <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="960">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="6">
 <td>
 Names: <ul class="list">
                  <li>
                    <a>Joe Doe</a>
            <ul>
                      <li>Mary Smith</li>  
                      <li>Carl Jackson</li>  
                      <li>John Smith</li>  
                    </ul>                
                 </li>
                </ul>
</td>
<td colspan="6">          
 &nbsp;
</td>
<td style="padding-left:260px">  
 Reg Date: <span style="text-transform: none;font-weight: bold;">April 01, 2015</span>
</td>
</tr>          
</tbody>
</table>

<br><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've cleaned up your example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/eyfbuauz/

```
var show;

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".thebody").hide();
 });

 $(".showme a").click(function(event){
   if (!show) { showhide($(this),"<a href=''>Joe Doe</a>",true); }
   else { showhide($(this),"<a href=''>Joe Doe</a>",false); }
   return false;
 });

function showhide(what,swaptext,swapstate){
   $(".thebody").toggle('fast');
   $(what).html(swaptext);
   show = swapstate;
}
```

You had some syntax errors in the javascript.

You need to define the show variable and the showhide function outside the jQuery callbacks.